# .net object size padding?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, clr

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says that

> the sizeof operator can be used only in unsafe code blocks. Although
>   you can use the Marshal.SizeOf method, the value returned by this
>   method is not always the same as the value returned by sizeof.

and

> Marshal.SizeOf returns the size after the type has been marshaled,
>   whereas sizeof returns the size as it has been allocated by the common
>   language runtime, including any ** padding **.

once ive read in the book : *c# via clr (page 522)*

that : 
[image]

questions :

1) does the padding mentioned in here :

[image]

is the **same** as mentioned in the book ?

AND

2) if i have object type of `Person` - how can i know its **TRUE SIZE** in MEMORY ?

### edit - why do i need that ?

please notice [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) :

they have a sample of  reading records :

```
 using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length))
            {

                int colorSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyColor)); //<--------HERE
                MyColor color;


                for (long i = 0; i < length; i += colorSize)
                {
                    accessor.Read(i, out color);
                    color.Brighten(10);
                    accessor.Write(i, ref color);
                }
            }
        }
```

if the size being reported by `MARSHAL.sizeOF` is **not** the size as `sizeOF` so - **which** should i choose ? it has to be accurate !!

according to this sample , they dont consider the padding  , and they should... ( or not...)

Comment: becuase if im using memorymappedfile - and have a file with many records (of person), i need to know the offset length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might seem disingenuous - but the size you're interested from the memory-mapped-file point of view is not the same as the size of that object in memory.  They might be called memory-mapped files, but in .Net that doesn't necessarily mean *quite* the same thing as it would in native code.  *(The underlying implementation is still the same, though - a section of logical memory is mapped to a section of a file, so the name is still correct)*

`sizeof` returns the correct size of the object in physical memory, including any padding bytes etc.  Therefore if you need to know the exact size of an object in native-memory terms, use that (but this *doesn't* apply to memory-mapped files as I'll explain in a moment).

As the documentation says, `Marshal.SizeOf` reports the size of an object from the .Net point of view, excluding the two hidden data items; which are used by the runtime only.

The example you have copied uses `Marshal.SizeOf` because the padding values are related *only to the physical object when in memory*.  When the object is serialized, only the *logical* .Net data is serialized.  When the object is loaded back again, those two padded values are re-assigned based on the state of the runtime at that point.  E.g. The type pointer might be different.  It would be meaningless to serialize them.  It would be like serializing a native pointer (not an offset) to disk - it's incredibly unlikely that the data it points to will be in the same place next time.

Ergo - if you want to know how much an array of 100 `Color` objects uses in physical memory - use `sizeof`; if you want to know how large the memroy-mapped file for the same data would be, use `Marshal.SizeOf`.

Comment: so why did they use `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyColor)); ` and not sizeof when they read in the memoryMappedFile ?

Comment: Updated my answer.  Think of the .Net object you know and love as logical data; with the actual memory the physical.  In general you never need the physical; even when using memory-mapped files - because in .Net you're dealing with a file mapped to logical data, not physical memory. Yes, the underlying implementation is truly using memory-mapped files; but .Net is then using that to seed other objects.

Comment: what about the padding issue from the book and from msdn - is it the same ?

Comment: I believe so - I don't know of any other padding the .Net runtime does.  The only possible thing could be word-boundary aligment, but that relates to the start of an object's location in memory, so I doubt that applies.

Comment: so- becuase im accesing via straight memory - i DO NEED THE size+padding  - hence i use the marshal.sizeOf ?

Comment: but you're not - .Net is responsible for adding the padding values at run time when it creates your object in response to reading some data from the memory-mapped file.  The memory you're reading is the logical view of the .Net data only...

Comment: can you elaborate `When the object is serialized,`....?what kjind of serialization occurs here